# get all checked rows on button click

Tags: php, jquery

i have a table in which data populating dynamically from db, now there is a checkbox on start of each row,what i want to do is when the user clicks on export button i want to get all those rows which are checked, this is my code!

**Dyanamic Table**

```
<table id="example" class="export_table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th id="not1">Check Box</th>
                            <th>Brand</th>
                            <th>Production Date</th>
                            <th>Expiry Date</th>
                            <th>Made In</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Batch Code</th>
                            <th>Created On</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        $i=0;
                        foreach($results as $r){
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<th id='not2'><input type='checkbox' name='checkedvalues' value='val_".$i."'/> </th>";
                            echo "<td>".$r['brand']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$r['production_date']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$r['expiry_date']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$r['madein']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$r['status']."</td>";
                            echo "<td id='main-print'>".$r['batch_code']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$r['created_on']."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            $i++;

                        }

                        ?>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#export").click(function(){

            var selectedvalues = [];

            $.each($("input[name='checkedvalues']:checked"), function(){

                selectedvalues.push($(this).val());

            });

            alert("Checked values are: " + selectedvalues.join(", "));

        });

    });
```

now i am getting only the values of selected checkbox which infact i dont want what i want is to generate an array which should be populated on the basis of checked attributes! it should take the full row on the basis of which checkbox is checked and then return me an array with all rows which are  checked, any help?

Comment: use `selectedvalues.push($(this).closest('tr'));` to get complete row

Comment: you are only getting the values since you are only pushing the values in the array `selectedvalues.push($(this).val());`

Comment: alright how to print the array? even if i run a loop it is returning data in a very weird format "Object { 0: <tr.even>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: <input> } 0 "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the row data as an object in "value" in each checkbox.
Something like below (inside your foreach loop)

```
foreach($results as $r){
        $obj = "{".$r['brand'].",".$r['production_date'].",".$r['expiry_date'].",".$r['madein'].",".$r['status'].",".$r['batch_code'].",".$r['created_on']."}";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th id='not2'><input type='checkbox' name='checkedvalues' value='".$obj."'/> </th>";
        ...
        ...
}
```

Now, your **selectedvalues** array will have javascript objects with each checked row.

p.s sorry for any php syntax errors

Comment: how does it validates which rows are selected and which is not?

Comment: the same jQuery logic that you have should get you the selected rows. We are just replacing the value of checkbox from "val_#" to "{<row_object>}

Comment: very efficient and interesting logic Azim bhai! keep up the good work! :)